# Column not appearing on Seek Predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

We have a table called "MealEvent" which has an index on EventDate,ConsumerId and some other columns. I have a poorly performing query which has an ON clause like this (me2 is MealEvent):

```
ON me2.CONSUMER_ID=fe.CONSUMER_ID and me2.MEAL_EVENT_DATE between fe.START_DATE and fe.END_DATE
```

When I look at the execution plan, I see the ConsumerId in the Predicate as opposed to Seek Predicate. I am wondering why does SQL Server opt to not use it in the Seek Predicate? Can I force it to use it in the Seek Predicate?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Full query, table and index definitions would be helpful, along with sharing the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Don't assume that this one attribute of the execution plan is the "problem" to be solved. Date columns are frequently used as the first column in an index because we tend to focus (i.e., filter) on rather small date ranges. And no one should be "tuning" based on a fragment of a query. You have a response that discusses the index usage but tuning should look at the complete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to flip the order of the key columns in the index.** The server cannot use a range predicate and then an equality predicate, the equality must come first

It should be `(CONSUMER_ID, MEAL_EVENT_DATE)`.

**The reason is simple:** When the server seeks the index for `MEAL_EVENT_DATE`, it does not have an exact key to look up, it wants a range of keys. It cannot then, within those keys, skip from one key to the next to get a single `CONSUMER_ID`.

But if `CONSUMER_ID` is first, then the server can seek directly to that key, then within that can look for the range of `MEAL_EVENT_DATE`.